# Creating output m-file in matlab

Tags: matlab

Suppose I have an M-file that calculates, for exampleת `d=a+b+c` (The values on `a`, `b`, `c` were given earlier).

What command should I use in order to produce an output M-file showing the result of this sum?

Answer (score 9):

In Matlab a semicolon ";" at the end of a line suppresses output.  So,

```
>> d=1+2;
>> d=1+2
d = 
    3
```

Or you can use *disp* as in the [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192796/creating-output-m-file-in-matlab#192841).

```
>> disp(num2str(d));
3
```

If you want to write the values of a variable to a file you can use either *dlmwrite* (use Matlab's help function to get more info) or *save* commands. For *dlmwrite*, the usage is basically

```
>> dlmwrite('filename',d,',')
```

which writes the vector (matrix), d, to the text file named *filename* using a comma as the delimiter between elements.

The other option is to use the *save* command, as in

```
>> save('filename','d')
```

which will save the variable 'd' to a MAT file (see *help save* for more information).  Hope this helps?

Answer (score 2):

To expand on [Azim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192796/creating-output-m-file-in-matlab#192859), the **save** command can be used to save variables to a text file.  In your case you would use:

```
save 'filename' d -ascii
```

Answer (score 1):

```
disp(num2str(d));
```